# Hydro on Arch Linux armv7h

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a Pandaboard ES and i installed Arch linux by following theese instructions => archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/ti/pandaboard

After that when i try to install ros-hydro by following these instructions => wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Arch

it fails at yaourt ros-hydro, saying that armv7h is not supported.

For example, ros-hydro-catkin 's PKGBUILD doesn't contain armv7h architecture in its arch array.  aur.archlinux.org/packages/ros-hydro-catkin/

When i download its PKGBUILD manually and add 'armv7h' to its arch array. it also gives error.

How can i install ros-hydro on my pandaboard? (i don't want to use ubuntu).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150071/hydro-on-arch-linux-armv7h/) by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-07**:
Why don't you want to use Ubuntu?

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-08**:
i'm not sure but i think ubuntu uses more resources. I tried installing ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gz and ROS Hydro. I was able to install them without any trouble, but when i ran hector_mapping package with a Hokuyo URG. It used %105 of cpu and map was disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm the guy in charge of those hydro packages on the AUR. I have only added support for `i686` and `x86_64`, since I cannot test package releases on ARM. However, several Arch users have been testing these packages with ARM, and apparently things were working for them.

First, make sure that you installed `base-devel` that [contains the base tools required by makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#Usage):

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel
```

If you have the PKGBUILDs, you can use the following command to build them:

```
makepkg -Acsi
```

The `-A` option ignores the target architecture, `-c` cleans up the directory after makepkg is done,  `-s` installs the needed dependencies (as explained [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/511)) and `-i` installs the package that you just built. However, there is absolutely no guarantee on the result since I have not tested things on ARM. Still, this is more or less an automatic source installation, so things should be fine.

Note that you can use `yaourt -G ros-hydro-package-name` to get the PKGBUILD.

Concerning the error you get when adding the architecture, try to give us more details, else we cannot do much for you. Remember that you may have some limited memory on your PandaBoard, and building packages can require quite a bit of it.

FYI, the project that includes the tools to generate those PKGBUILDs + the PKGBUILDs themselves, is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/bchretien/arch-ros-stacks). You can clone it, `cd` to the packages that you want, and run `makepkg` from there. This is probably the easiest route for you.

**UPDATE:** some packages cannot be compiled on ARM right now. This is the same for every Linux distribution. For instance, `roslisp` depends on `sbcl` which is not available on ARM (cf. https://github.com/ros/roslisp/issues/14).
Also, since more and more people seem to be installing the AUR packages for ROS on ARM, from now on I'll use `'any'` for the supported architectures. This should ease the install process for ARM users, but there will not be any guarantee on the result.

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-08**:
hi, first of all thank you very much for responding me very soon.
i cloned git repository that you provided.
However, when i try to makepkg ros-build-tools it gives me this error.

makepkg -Acsi --asroot
==> ERROR: Cannot find the strip binary required for object file stripping.

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-04-08**:
You need to install base-devel to compile stuff: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#Usage , this should solve your problem. Also I just updated the md5sums for ros-build-tools, just use git pull to get my latest changes.

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-08**:
I started installing ros-hydro-ros-base with yaourt (yaourt ros-hydro-ros-base) and i was editing every PKGBUILD to add armv7h to its arch array. However, it gives me an error at this point "Install or build missing dependencies for ros-hydro-roslisp:
error: target not found: sbcl"

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-04-08**:
@lvntbkdmr: well, sbcl is in [extra], check in /ect/pacman.conf that [extra] is enabled, then run: sudo pacman -Sy

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-09**:
when i type pacman -S sbcl , it cannot find the package. i checked my pacman.conf extra is uncommented i'm using Geo-IP based mirror. [http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/$arch/$repo](http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/%7B26f347b8-3e6e-4f97-a227-7eb22b808f5d%7Drepo)

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-04-09**:
@lvntbkdmr: then sbcl may not have been released for ARM. You can, once again, try to compile it yourself (https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/sbcl), or ask the guys in charge of Arch packing for ARM (https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs )

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-09**:
sbcl is required by roslisp package. and according to these guys => answers.ros.org/question/80931/disable-roslisp/ , roslisp is not necessray so i skipped that package and continue installing. Guess what? i have successfully built ROS Hydro !!! :D (not full of course, just ros-base) thank you very much !

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-04-09**:
Note however that I don't know whether sbcl has been indeed ported to ARM successfully. It may be worth checking whether there's actually a sbcl for ARM on Debian as well... And apparently, there's not.

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-04-09**:
@lvntbkdmr: oh alright, good! I'll  make it optional in the package then ;-) FYI: https://github.com/ros/roslisp/issues/14 ("Move from SBCL")